# Why do boottimes differ daily?

Tags: firewall, startup, kubuntu, snap

My boottimes differ on a daily basis ( in Kubuntu, which I use as a daily driver ). Sometimes the BPFilter ( UFW ) will start displaying errors for about 10 seconds. Sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes my snaps take 10-15 seconds.

I'm not directly connected to the internet, I always have to log into the network ( which is normal ).

It is only about 10-15 seconds, that does not bather me that much. It is the irregularity that I'm curious about. Can anybody explain that to me? And if I could fix it, even better!

Here is my output:

> patrick@Lappy:~$ sudo systemd-analyze blame
> [sudo] password for patrick:
> 8.751s ufw.service
> 2.872s apt-daily-upgrade.service
> 2.678s tlp.service
> 1.251s fwupd-refresh.service
> 1.080s dev-nvme0n1p7.device
> 1.079s fwupd.service
> 944ms snapd.service
> 485ms dev-loop15.device
> 471ms dev-loop10.device
> 469ms dev-loop13.device
> 467ms dev-loop14.device
> 467ms dev-loop16.device
> 460ms dev-loop12.device
> 450ms dev-loop9.device
> 449ms dev-loop8.device
> 448ms dev-loop17.device
> 435ms dev-loop11.device
> 421ms dev-loop0.device
> 359ms dev-loop3.device
> 350ms dev-loop5.device
> 349ms dev-loop4.device
> 346ms dev-loop7.device
> 342ms dev-loop1.device
> 341ms dev-loop6.device
> 340ms dev-loop2.device
> 337ms udisks2.service
> 283ms ua-messaging.service
> 252ms systemd-logind.service
> 248ms networkd-dispatcher.service
> 223ms accounts-daemon.service
> 191ms gpu-manager.service

```
I'm using an HP Envy C-17 with 
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04 (Btrfs)
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.14.14-051414-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 15,3 GiB 
in tripleboot with Mint 20.1 (ext4) and Windows 10 (NTFS) .
```

Comment: You seem to have found a potential culprit : BPFilter which sometimes sends error messages. It would be interesting to know how it is configurated (with IP address ? IP resolved names ?) and which errors are sent.

Comment: Too often it's about DNS. Check this https://www.google.com/search?q=ufw+slow+to+start

Comment: How can I find that out. I have maps in 'usr/scr/linux-headers' with a Kconfig file ( textdocument ) and a Makefile build file in it. I have a bpfilter.ko in 'user/lib/modules/kernelname/kernel/net/bpfilter', some empty documents called BPFilter_UMH an BPFilter in 'usr/src/kernelname/include/config' and 'C-header'files called bpfilter.h in 'usr/src/linux-header-kernelname/include/linux. I have no clue about this kind of stuff.